# Change order of layout rows and columns with Bootstrap and CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following order of cols in Bootstrap in desktop screen:

COL-A COL-B COL-C

```html
<div class"container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">Text 1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4"><img src="myimage"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">Text 2</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

When I change my screen to medium size (min width: 768px to 990px), I want to achieve the next:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please dd your code and your question is not clear.. when you want to change the order?

Comment: When the screen pass from md to sm screen in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your diagram, just do two columns of half-width, with the 2nd column having two rows within it containing full width columns.

Something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">Column 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">Column 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `sm` breakpoints and width numbers should be optional if you're only doing these.

Comment: I refer this distribution when changes to sm screen.